# Why is my Android phone layout different then my layout on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout

The layout of my MainActivity on my phone appears very differently than the layout I see on the code editor. Images are included. I am using a TabbedView. However, the problem still exists on any layout I choose (empty/tabbed).

What can I do to solve this problem?

[image: Layout Android Studio]
[image: Layout Samsung Galaxy S7 WQHD screen]

I am concerned about the text "Hello world" in the middle, not in the top left corner. I follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaH4PQpV4BM) and in the tutorial it is correctly positioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as expected, because `section_label` TextView width is `wrap_content` it changes, depending on what text it displays. And the 2nd TextViews position depends on it, so it changes too. You should be able to verify this by setting various length texts in your layout editor.

For what you want to achieve, `RelativeLayout` is not the best choice and you may want to use i.e. `LinearLayout` instead, with its orientation set to `vertical` and `layout_gravity` of second `TextView` set to right

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I just realize i asked a dumb question, lol. Because when I delete the first TextView, it is displayed exactly as I want it

Answer (score 1):

This is happen because you are using the RelativeLayout in the relativelayout we can arrage our views in custom position wise by the help of give the android:id=@+id/some_id like this if you want your second view is shown just below the first view then give them the property         android:layout_below="@id/view1" in your second view
Please read all the documentation of RelativeLayout form this link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html